# Git requires commandline dev tools - new xcode update

Tags: xcode, git

Xcode had a recent update leading to git commands not working. Message showed up saying commandline dev tools was needed

Edit Fixed:

First I was being prompted to reinstall commandLine tools over and over when trying to accept the terms

I FIXED this by opening xcode and confirming the new update information

NOTE:
I moved this here as another thread had a mix of other issues with the error it was in

Comment: This is strictly an XCode issue: XCode overrides your working Git installation with a broken one. Doing the XCode confirmation allows the XCode replacement Git to run, but you might wish to re-replace that one with a more modern one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I was being prompted to reinstall commandLine tools over and over when trying to accept the terms

I FIXED this by opening xcode and confirming the new update information